# How to show Tooltip only onClick in react toolbox

Tags: reactjs, react-toolbox

There is a [Tooltip example](http://react-toolbox.io/#/components/tooltip) in [react-toolbox](http://react-toolbox.io/#/) offical docs. How can i show Tooltip only onClick event on Input.

Comment: Referencing the documentation, tooltipShowOnClick property doesn't help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show tooltip on mouse enter, you should fork the project and make following changes:

`at components/tooltip/Tooltip.js:`

```
handleMouseEnter = (event) => {
        this.activate(this.calculatePosition(event.currentTarget));
        if (this.props.onMouseEnter) this.props.onMouseEnter(event);
      };

handleMouseLeave = (event) => {
        this.deactivate();
        if (this.props.onMouseLeave) this.props.onMouseLeave(event);
      };
```

TO

```
handleMouseEnter = (event) => {
        return false;
      };

handleMouseLeave = (event) => {
        return false;
      };
```